# Finding SQL server deadlock cause

Tags: c++, sql-server, multithreading, stored-procedures

I have a simple c++ program running on MSVC using an ODBC connection to execute a stored procedure.

When running it on the main thread it works fine, but when I attempt to multithread the same class I am getting this error:

> (Process ID XX) was deadlocked on lock resource....

As mentioned above I can run it fine on the main thread and also on two threads with no issues.

This is how I spawn, use and join the threads:

```
historical apple("AAPL");
historical google("GOOG");
historical yahoo("YHOO");
historical samsung("005930.KS");
historical ibm("IBM");
auto t1 = thread([&] {apple.go(); });
auto t2 = thread([&] {google.go(); });
auto t3 = thread([&] {yahoo.go(); });
auto t4 = thread([&] {samsung.go(); });
auto t5 = thread([&] {ibm.go(); });

//writer(his.getHistorical()); // this writes to the file test.csv
t1.join();
t2.join();
t3.join();
t4.join();
t5.join();
```

I know it looks like shit, but I'm basically trying to see how hard I can push the software before making it look nice and more formatted.

This is how I call the stored procedure:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "database_con.h"

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Show errors from the SQLHANDLE

void database_con::show_error(unsigned int handletype, const SQLHANDLE& handle)
{
    SQLWCHAR sqlstate[1024];
    SQLWCHAR message[1024];
    if (SQL_SUCCESS == SQLGetDiagRec(handletype, handle, 1, sqlstate, NULL, message, 1024, NULL))
        wcout << "Message: " << message << "\nSQLSTATE: " << sqlstate << endl;
}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Builds the stored procedure query.

std::wstring database_con::buildQuery(vector<std::wstring> input, string symbol)
{
    std::wstringstream builder;
    builder << L"EXEC sp_addHistorical " << "@Symbol='" << L"" << StringToWString(symbol) << "'," <<
        "@Date='" << (wstring)L"" << input.at(0) << "'," <<
        "@Open=" << (wstring)L"" << input.at(1) << "," <<
        "@Close=" << (wstring)L"" << input.at(2) << "," <<
        "@MaxPrice=" << (wstring)L"" << input.at(3) << "," <<
        "@MinPrice=" << (wstring)L"" << input.at(4) << "," <<
        "@Volume=" << (wstring)L"" << input.at(5) << ";";
    return builder.str();
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Adds a substring of the string before the delimiter to a vector<wstring> that is returned.

std::vector<wstring> database_con::parseData(wstring line, char delim) {
    size_t pos = 0;
    std::vector<std::wstring> vOut;
    while ((pos = line.find(delim)) != std::string::npos) {
        vOut.push_back(line.substr(0, pos));
        line.erase(0, pos + 1);
    }
    vOut.push_back(line.substr(0, pos));
    return vOut;
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Converts a std::string to a std::wstring

std::wstring database_con::StringToWString(const std::string& s)
{
    std::wstring temp(s.length(), L' ');
    std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(), temp.begin());
    return temp;
}
void database_con::historicalLooper(string historical) {

}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Constructs a database connector object with the historical data and its symbol

database_con::database_con(std::string historical, string symbol){
    /*
    Set up the handlers
    */

    /* Allocate an environment handle */
    SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &env);
    /* We want ODBC 3 support */
    SQLSetEnvAttr(env, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (void *)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0);
    /* Allocate a connection handle */
    SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, env, &dbc);

    /* Connect to the DSN */
    SQLDriverConnectW(dbc, NULL, L"DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=ERA-PC-STUART\\JBK_DB;DATABASE=master;UID=geo;PWD=kalle123;", SQL_NTS, NULL, 0, NULL, SQL_DRIVER_COMPLETE);
    /* Check for success */
    if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, dbc, &stmt))
    {
        show_error(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, dbc);
        std::cout << "Failed to connect";
    }
    _mSymbol = symbol;
    std::wstringstream stream(StringToWString(historical));
    std::wstring line;
    int row = 0;
    while (std::getline(stream, line)) {
        if (row > 0) {
            vector<wstring> vHistorical = parseData(L"" + line, ',');
            std::wstring SQL = buildQuery(vHistorical, _mSymbol);

            if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLExecDirectW(stmt, const_cast<SQLWCHAR*>(SQL.c_str()), SQL_NTS)) {
                std::cout << "Execute error " << std::endl;
                show_error(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, stmt);
                std::wcout << L"Unsuccessful Query: " << SQL << std::endl;
            }
            // Close Cursor before next iteration starts:
            SQLRETURN closeCursRet = SQLFreeStmt(stmt, SQL_CLOSE);
            if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(closeCursRet))
            {
                show_error(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, stmt);
                // maybe add some handling for the case that closing failed.
            }
        }
        row++;
    }
    std::cout << "Query " << _mSymbol << " ready" << std::endl;

}

database_con::~database_con() {

}
```

And finally this is the stored procedure:

```
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_addHistorical
    @Symbol nchar(10),@Date datetime,
    @Open decimal(12,2),@Close decimal(12,2),@MinPrice decimal(12,2),
    @MaxPrice decimal(12,2),@Volume int
AS 
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    MERGE HistoricalStock WITH (UPDLOCK) AS myTarget
        USING (SELECT @Symbol AS Symbol,
        @Date AS Date, @Open AS [Open], @Close AS [Close],
        @MinPrice AS MinPrice, @MaxPrice AS MaxPrice,@Volume AS Volume) AS mySource
        ON mySource.Symbol = myTarget.Symbol AND mySource.Date = myTarget.Date
        WHEN MATCHED 
            THEN UPDATE 
                SET [Open] = mySource.[Open], [Close] = mySource.[Close],
                MinPrice = mySource.MinPrice, MaxPrice = mySource.MaxPrice, Volume = mySource.Volume            
        WHEN NOT MATCHED
            THEN
                INSERT(Symbol,Date,[Open],[Close],MinPrice,MaxPrice,Volume)
                VALUES(@Symbol,@Date,@Open,@Close,@MinPrice,@MaxPrice,@Volume);
    COMMIT 
GO
```

Any sort of help or advice on either how it's all structured or pointers to good examples regarding the issue I'm facing would be greatly appreciated.

I'm somewhat new to SQL server (more importantly to stored procedures) and can't really figure out what is wrong, even though I understand what a deadlock is.

Thanks!

Comment: The way you're calling the sproc from C++ is vulnerable to SQL Injection. I don't know MSVC's database libraries, sorry, but in C# I'd be creating a collection of parameters and assigning it to the connection object, which protects against that while giving other benefits.

Comment: As for why it's deadlocking - is it always deadlocking with certain combinations of parameters and not with others, or is it any combination of data when run multithreaded that's causing this behaviour?

Comment: have you tried to rollback  transaction in case of error  ?

Comment: As i understand it there is no way to parameterize odbc input to SQL from c++. There won't be any way to use an sql injection though as this code will run on the server without any user input. Much like an automated data gatherer.

Comment: Strangely enough it is OK the first 5 seconds or so, then one error message appears with the deadlocked query. The following seconds it exponentially gets worse with more and more error messages until I manually stop the program.

Comment: I have not attempted to rollback in case of error as I have absolutely no clue what it is :p

Comment: It looks like each of your queries uses independent rows of data and are not order dependent. If that's actually the case, can you change your stored procedure so that the `SET TRANSACTION` line reads `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED` and test again?

Comment: Do you have indexes on this table?